# How to extract information from starting certain value in a column in R?

Tags: r, filter

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                     X1 = c(1,1,0,2,8,0,1,3,4,5),
                     X2 = c(0,2,3,NA,NA,6,NA,3,1,1),
                     X3 = c(1,2,0,4,NA,6,7,5,NA,NA),
                     X4 = c(4,NA,6,7,8,0,0,0,7,6),
                     X5 = c(0,1,3,0,0,6,5,4,0,0),
                     X6 = c(1,0,3,4,3,2,1,7,8,7),
                     X7 = c(1,2,NA,4,5,7,8,NA,8,5),
                     X8 = c(2,6,NA,6,5,NA,3,NA,NA,3))

> df
   id X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
1   1  1  0  1  4  0  1  1  2
2   2  1  2  2 NA  1  0  2  6
3   3  0  3  0  6  3  3 NA NA
4   4  2 NA  4  7  0  4  4  6
5   5  8 NA NA  8  0  3  5  5
6   6  0  6  6  0  6  2  7 NA
7   7  1 NA  7  0  5  1  8  3
8   8  3  3  5  0  4  7 NA NA
9   9  4  1 NA  7  0  8  8 NA
10 10  5  1 NA  6  0  7  5  3
```

.

I have a dataset looks like this. I would like to extract for each id to grab all available numerical values after the last 0 for each id, and I would also would like to grab the last numeric value before the last 0 in a row. How can I extract that?

The desired outcome would be:

```
> df_new
   id a b1 b2 b3 b4
1   1 4  1  1  2 NA
2   2 1  2  6 NA NA
3   3 3  6  3  3 NA
4   4 7  4  4  6 NA
5   5 8  3  5  5 NA
6   6 6  6  2  7 NA
7   7 7  5  1  8  3
8   8 5  4  7 NA NA
9   9 7  8  8 NA NA
10 10 6  7  5  3 NA
```

Comment: There are no 0s in your example dataset so it's a bit hard to know what you want. Could you provide example output please?

Comment: each id has 0 or 0s. After the last 0, I would like to grab all available numeric values, and also, the last numeric value before the last 0, I would like to get that value as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First look for the condition with `which` and get the position of the last zero using `max`, then use this info to get the desired positional data. Finally format the output by removing the trailing `NA`s and add the expected column names.

Edit: Added a failsafe in case there's no zero in a line

```
df_tmp <- apply(df, 1, \(x){
  pos <- which(x == 0)
  pos <- ifelse(length(pos) == 0, ncol(x) + 1, max(pos))
  c(x[pos - 1], x[c(pos + 1 : length(x))])
})

df_new <- data.frame(df$id, t(df_tmp[rowSums(df_tmp, na.rm=T) != 0,]))

colnames(df_new) <- c("id", "a", paste0("b", 1 : (ncol(df_new) - 2)))
```

output

```
df_new
   id a b1 b2 b3 b4
1   1 4  1  1  2 NA
2   2 1  2  6 NA NA
3   3 3  6  3  3 NA
4   4 7  4  4  6 NA
5   5 8  3  5  5 NA
6   6 6  6  2  7 NA
7   7 7  5  1  8  3
8   8 5  4  7 NA NA
9   9 7  8  8 NA NA
10 10 6  7  5  3 NA
```

All in one go without temporary data

```
setNames(apply(df, 1, \(x){
  pos <- which(x == 0)
  pos <- ifelse(length(pos) == 0, ncol(x) + 1, max(pos))
  c(x[pos - 1], x[c(pos + 1 : length(x))])}) |> 
  (\(x) data.frame(df$id, t(x[rowSums(x, na.rm=T) != 0,])))(), 
    c("id", "a", paste0("b", 1:(ncol(df_new) - 2))))
```